# Google Sheet App Scrip Update Cell based on values of another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to update cell values on open of a sheet and on edit of a specific cell.

**On Open**

In the sample sheet sheet 'Transactions' I am trying to set a text month(Q) and year(R) based on the date(B) if the either Q or R is blank.

**On Edit**

I am try to set Group(P) in sheet 'Transactions' based on the value in category(D) by looking finding the matching Group(B) value that corresponds to Category(A) in sheet "List".  I'd like to do this both if Group(P) is blank and Category(A) is not blank or the user edits category(D) in sheet 'Transactions'.

I've been looking around a bit today for something similar on stack flow but haven't quite found it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QBq0fxty8K55UaM_uS42GY7dMpCHg4ClGMI4UtU-0T4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So, are you sure that you need a script? It can be done with script. But @PGSystemTester solutions with formulas looks quite enough. Especially if you aren't into JS coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use [Array Formulas](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/array-formula-intro/)?

Put this in the Months column, starting in row 2.

```
=FILTER(text(B2:B,"MMMM"),Not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
```

Put this in the Year:

```
=FILTER(text(B2:B,"YYYY"),Not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
```

Put this for the match:

```
=filter(VLOOKUP(D2:D,List!A:B,2,false),not(ISBLANK(B2:B)))
```

Make sure the rows below are clear, and it will auto-update as values are created.

Comment: The only reason I was look at app script is I had the following and the sheet transactions is automatically updated by an outside service.  So each time a new row was added it broke the array.  However it could just be my array, I'll try yours and see how it goes.  I'd much rather simplicity but apps scripts are interesting.

ARRAYFORMULA({"Month";IF(B2:B="",,TEXT(B2:B,"mmmm"))})

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions they are great.